# Собственный maven-plugin

Tags: maven, java

Подскажите, можно ли maven-plugin запустить из java-кода, а не из pom-файла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. По сути плагин к Maven представляет собой класс, реализующий интерфейс [`Mojo`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/Mojo.html). Ваша задача - подключить к проекту jar-ку, содержащую плагин, создать экземпляр класса плагина, установить значения параметров, необходимых ему для работы, и вызвать метод `execute`. Также к проекту придётся подключить библиотеки самого Maven'а.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Comment: fori1ton, спасибо за помощь